# How To Position a Picture on A Second Page Of A Word Document VB6

Tags: ms-word, vb6

I am making a program that repeatedly creates pages of an undefined quantity, and on the top of all the pages is a logo that is in a certain position. If I have everything in a for loop and at the end I include these commands to make a page break:

`Set oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range
 oRng.InsertBreak`

The second time (and subsequent times) the table I make goes on the the next page, but the image does not. I have tried setting the "top" property to

`distFromTop + pageLength * pageNumber`.

I would assume it might have to do with the anchor property, but I have no idea what data type that even gets or how it affects the placement
I insert the image using:

`oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\name\Desktop\file.jpg", , , CentimetersToPoints(1.3), CentimetersToPoints(0.9 + pageLength * j), CentimetersToPoints(6.1), CentimetersToPoints(2.9)`

The picture adds multiple times, but both to .9 from the top on the first page and 1.3 from the left, on the first page.

**How can I make the pic go .9 from the top of a certain page**

**EDIT:** I would like to avoid putting it in a header because that would mess up the alignment of the other elements of the doc

Comment: Is there a reason for not adding the image to the page header - which you only need do once?

Comment: I would like to avoid using headers because I would like a specific place on the document for the non-inline shape to go

Comment: Your reason for not using a header is unclear. If you position the Shape behind or in front of the text it won't affect the alignments of anything?

Comment: As to your question: insert the pictures after a new page has been generated. Make sure you pass a RANGE object to the Anchor argument, as I emphasized in my previous Answer to you, that RANGE object needing to be ON the page where the Shape should go. From the code you've posted it appears you're not passing an ANCHOR argument at all!

Comment: «I would like to avoid using headers because I would like a specific place on the document for the non-inline shape to go» That makes no sense at all. Placing the content in the header allows the one instance to be placed anywhere on the page for all pages. Inserting the content into the document body is liable to result in it moving around when the body content is edited - or even when it's viewed on a system using a different printer driver.

Comment: This is tagged both VB6 and VBA - are both appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So what worked for me was this:

`Set oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range
 oRng.InsertBreak
 oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture "C:\Users\me\Desktop\file.jpg", , , CentimetersToPoints(1.3), 
      CentimetersToPoints(0.9), CentimetersToPoints(6.1), CentimetersToPoints(2.9), 
      oDoc.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range`

I still don't quite understand why it works, because the documentation for a range objects / anchors was fairly hard for me to understand...  I tried this out and this worked. For my purposes that worked, but if anyone knows why that works I would love to know

Thanks for your answers